# Recognizing a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have
$$
\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\ \sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22}\end{pmatrix},\quad S=\begin{pmatrix}s_{11} & s_{12} \\ s_{21} & s_{22}\end{pmatrix}
$$
both of which are actually covariance matrices of two $2\times 1$ random vectors. So, in particular, $\Sigma$ and $S$ are symmetric. Now I have a $4\times 4$ matrix:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{11}s_{11} & \sigma_{11}s_{12} & \sigma_{12}s_{11} & \sigma_{12}s_{12} \\
\sigma_{12}s_{11} & \sigma_{12}s_{12} & \sigma_{22}s_{11} & \sigma_{22}s_{12} \\
\sigma_{11}s_{12} & \sigma_{11}s_{22} & \sigma_{12}s_{12} & \sigma_{12}s_{22} \\
\sigma_{12}s_{12} & \sigma_{12}s_{22} & \sigma_{22}s_{12} & \sigma_{22}s_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I would like to write $A$ as a function of $\Sigma$ and $S$ (without referring to $\sigma$'s and $s$') using matrix operations ($\otimes$, multiplication, inversion, addition, and maybe something else I cannot think of). How do I do that please?

Comment: You sure that's the expression you want? Both $\sigma_{21}$ and $s_{21}$ are unused.

Comment: @Adriankeister They are used. Please see the remark about symmetry.

Comment: The honorable member from $\mathbb R^{4\times4}$ is recognized.

Comment: @yurnero: Ah, I see. You're quite right. If only I had read the question a bit closer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your matrix as $A = (S \otimes \Sigma)P$, where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product and
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1}
$$

Comment: This doesn't quite look right to me. I tried it out in the Wolfram Dev Platform, and the $(3,1)$ position, for example, ought to have $\sigma_{11}$ but your expression yields $\sigma_{21}.$ Think you might be on the right track, though.

Comment: @AdrianKeister That's what I get for trying to do this in my head.  I suspect that there's some other permutation matrix $Q$ such that $A = Q(\Sigma \otimes S)P$

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I'm pretty sure the algebra of this problem is related to the algebra of a related question I have asked earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2899662/178464. There, your matrix $P$ shows up in the correct answer.

Comment: Based on your original answer, I have arrived at $(S\otimes\Sigma)P$ which I think is correct. I'll gladly tick if you verify this and modify your original answer accordingly.

Comment: In fact, $(\Sigma\otimes S)P=A'$.

Comment: If by $A'$ you mean the transpose of $A$, that's not quite right, either.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Can you point out the error? I triple-checked on Mathematica. It seems okay to me. ("It" = both claims $(S\otimes\Sigma)P=A$ and $(\Sigma\otimes S)P=A'$.)

Comment: @yurnero I think $(S \otimes \Sigma)P$ was what I meant to put down initially.  You may find it interesting to observe that $P(S \otimes \Sigma)P = \Sigma \otimes S$.  Consequently, we can write
$$
A = (S \otimes \Sigma)P = P(\Sigma \otimes S)
$$

Comment: Code: `A={{a11, a12},{a12, a22}}; B={{b11, b12},{b12, b22}}; P={{1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1}}; MatrixForm[ArrayReshape[TensorProduct[A,B],{4,4}].P]` doesn't give $A$ or $A^{T}$. The subscript patterns don't line up with what you want. The code above yields $$\left[\begin{matrix}a11 b11 &a11 b12 &a11 b12 &a11 b22\\ a12 b11 &a12 b12 &a12 b12 &a12 b22 \\ a12 b11 &a12 b12 &a12 b12 &a12 b22 \\ a22 b11 &a22 b12 &a22 b12 &a22 b22\end{matrix}\right].$$You can see that this result is neither $A$ nor $A^{T}.$

Comment: Hang on. The `ArrayReshape` is not doing what I thought it was doing...

Comment: Right, I can agree that $A'=(\Sigma\otimes S)P.$ No doubt the other expressions are correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but one way to do it may be through combining Kronecker product and Hadamard product:

$$ \biggl(\begin {bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end {bmatrix} \otimes S \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end {bmatrix}\biggr) \circ \biggl(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end {bmatrix}\ \otimes \Sigma \otimes \begin {bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end {bmatrix}\biggr) $$